# WP app getting confused about posts and pages

Tags: rss, feed

I wanted to use the Wordpress iPad app (3.1.1) for my new blog. Somehow the app seems to be a little bit confused for me. It shows some of my posts as pages and vice versa. It does show a lot of old post, bot none of the newer ones. I have no idea why that is.

On my server I have the following WP setup:

- Wordpress 3.4.1
- Theme: Twentyeleven
- Active Plugins:
  ** Akismet
  ** Jetpack

That's it. The only thing I consider noteworthy besides those facts is that I've imported some of my old blog posts (from BlogEngine.net) via BlogML when I started my new WP blog a few weeks ago.

My page seems to have an issue with the RSS feed as well. Once I add the feed to a reader it downloads all the articles properly. But new posts never make it through. I'm not sure if that helps diagnosing the other problem.

Anyway, thanks a lot!
–f

-- I'm re-posting this here since I did not get any feedback on the Wordpress forum yet.

**Update**

I posted the screenshots requested by Damien to my website (to make it funny: as a WP page ;)). The page you see is missing on the screenshots. On the website it show's up as expected. The app does not show it at all. So here it is:

http://blog.flohei.de/wordpress-issues/

Comment: Could you post a link to your blog and perhaps to the RSS feed as well?  Also have you logged in to WP-Admin and confirmed that there are no mixed up posts n pages ... sounds like the import from blogengine is the culprit not the iPad app.

Comment: Hi Damien! Sure. The blog is http://blog.flohei.de and the feed is at http://blog.flohei.de/feed. I'm not sure what you mean by confirming that posts and pages are not mixed up. What I can say is that everything *seems* to be fine in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was the big post ids that were generated when importing from Tumblr. I wrote a quick and dirty script to handle this. See:

http://blog.flohei.de/2012/08/fixing-the-post-id-231-1-issue/

Thanks again, Damien!

Answer (score 0):

@Flo I had a look at your blog and also the RSS feed via Google Reader and things look OK. All I can say is that probably the IMPORT file from bloglines was *corrupt* and some of your posts got marked as pages.

The only way for me to prove that would be to see a screenshot of your PAGES from WP-Admin > Pages > All Pages

Do you have any examples of what you expected to be a POST vs a PAGE?

Comment: When you first add the feed to the reader it does actually pull all the entries. But when I add a new one it does not get through. I did already look at the database. There are two entries marked as pages (that's correct), a few as attachments and the rest as posts. For me it looks like that's correct. I'll update my post w/ the requested screenshots in a minute.

Comment: can you add a post to your WordPress site and ill check that it comes through on Google Reader

Comment: Done. Great. And now, of course, it does show up in Reeder.app on my computer. So maybe it's just the other issue with the app that I want to fix.

Comment: Hi @Flo are you using the latest version of the iPad app ... It's now got a layout for iPad that looks similar to Twitter with sliding panels. It's different to your picture http://blog.flohei.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/IMG_2415.png and the link on Itunes is http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/wordpress/id335703880?mt=8

Comment: The screenshot shows the iPhone version, you're right. But it's the same problem for both iOS versions. And yes, they are both the most recently ones.